# add rows in dataTable from different buttons asp.net]

Tags: asp.net

Hello i have problem with data Table. I want to insert new row in data Table every time when user click on button.I have 10 buttons and when user click on button 1,it insert new row but when user clicks on button 2 existing row is replaced with new one. HELP!

////here i call  methods for adding new rows from button clicks

```
 private void RemoveDuplicates (Data_Table dt)                         
        {

    if (ViewState["Markici"] != null)
    {
        dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];

        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int i = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Cena1"].ToString() == dtCurrentTable.Rows[j]["Cena1"].ToString())
                    {

                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i].Delete();
                        break;


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();

      // ViewState["Markici"] = dtCurrentTable;
      //  Repeater1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
      //  Repeater1.DataBind();

            AddNewRecordRowToGrid();                            
          AddNewRecordRowToGridf(); 


        decimal vkupno = 0m;
        vkupno += Convert.ToDecimal(Label6.Text);

        decimal vkupno2 = 0m;
        vkupno2 += Convert.ToDecimal(Label17.Text);
        vkupno += vkupno2;

        Label26.Text = vkupno.ToString();
        //xml table
   //     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     //   ds.Tables.Add(dtCurrentTable);

        //binding Gridview with New Row  
        GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView2.DataBind();

    }
}
```

//method for adding row, call this in button click 9

```
  private void AddNewRecordRowToGrid()
    {         
        int counter;

        if (Request.Cookies["kasa"] == null)

            counter = 0;


        else
        {
            counter = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["kasa"].Value);

        }
        counter++;

        Response.Cookies["kasa"].Value = counter.ToString();
        Response.Cookies["kasa"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(2);

        if (ViewState["Markici"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

                    drCurrentRow["FirmaID"] = Request.Cookies["firma"].Value; 
                    drCurrentRow["Godina"] = Request.Cookies["godina"].Value;
                    drCurrentRow["KasaID"] = Request.Cookies["kasa"].Value;
                    drCurrentRow["MarkicaID"] = counter; 
                    drCurrentRow["Datum"] = DateTime.Now;
                    drCurrentRow["Masa"] = Session["masa39"];
                    drCurrentRow["VrabotenID"] = Session["New"];
                    drCurrentRow["Artikal"] = Label3.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Cena1"] = Label4.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Kolicina"] = Label5.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Smena"] = Session["smena1"];
                    drCurrentRow["VkIznos"] = Label6.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["VkDanok"] = Label8.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["SySDatum"] = DateTime.Now;
                    drCurrentRow["Vid"] = Label23.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Edmera"] = Label10.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["ArtikalID"] = Label33.Text;
                }
                /*
                for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[i].IsNull(0) == true)
                    {
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i].Delete();
                        dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
                    }
                }*/

                //Removing initial blank row  
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                {
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[0].Delete();
                    dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();

                }

                //Added New Record to the DataTable  
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //storing DataTable to ViewState  
                ViewState["Markici"] = dtCurrentTable;

                //binding Gridview with New Row  
                GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                GridView2.DataBind();


            }
        }
    }

    // call this in button 10 click
    private void AddNewRecordRowToGridf()
    {

        if (ViewState["Markici"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["Markici"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {


                    //Creating new row and assigning values  
                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

                    drCurrentRow["FirmaID"] = Request.Cookies["firma"].Value;
                    drCurrentRow["Godina"] = Request.Cookies["godina"].Value;
                    drCurrentRow["KasaID"] = Request.Cookies["kasa"].Value;
                    drCurrentRow["MarkicaID"] = Request.Cookies["kasa"].Value; 
                    drCurrentRow["Datum"] = DateTime.Now;
                    drCurrentRow["Masa"] = Session["masa39"];
                    drCurrentRow["VrabotenID"] = Session["New"];
                    drCurrentRow["Artikal"] = Label12.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Cena1"] = Label13.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Kolicina"] = Label11.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Smena"] = Session["smena1"];
                    drCurrentRow["VkIznos"] = Label17.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["VkDanok"] = Label18.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["SySDatum"] = DateTime.Now;
                    drCurrentRow["Vid"] = Label24.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Edmera"] = Label16.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["ArtikalID"] = Label34.Text;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[i].IsNull(0) == true)
                    {
                        dtCurrentTable.Rows[i].Delete();
                        dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
                    }
                }
                /*
                //Removing initial blank row  
                if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                {
                   dtCurrentTable.Rows[0].Delete();
                   dtCurrentTable.Rows[1].Delete();
                    dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();

                }
                */
                //Added New Record to the DataTable  
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //storing DataTable to ViewState  
                ViewState["Markici"] = dtCurrentTable;
                //binding Gridview with New Row  
                GridView2.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;


                GridView2.DataBind();
            }
        }
    protected void Button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveDuplicates(dt);
      }
    protected void Button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveDuplicates(dt);
      }
       // create DataTable
    private void AddDefaultFirstRecord()
    {

        //creating DataTable  
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        dt.TableName = "Markici";
        //creating columns for DataTable  
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirmaID", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Godina", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("KasaID", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MarkicaID", typeof(System.Int64)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Datum", typeof(System.DateTime)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Masa", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VrabotenID", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Artikal", typeof(System.String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cena1", typeof(System.String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Kolicina", typeof(System.Decimal)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Smena", typeof(System.Int32)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VkIznos", typeof(System.Decimal)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VkDanok", typeof(System.Decimal)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SysDatum", typeof(System.DateTime)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Vid", typeof(System.String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EdMera", typeof(System.String)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ArtikalID", typeof(System.String)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        ViewState["Markici"] = dt;

        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: You should have something like a unique Id in your data rows. So you can uniquely identify each rows.Then you can replace the row that inserted from button1 click by clicking button2

Answer (score 0):

Add dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges(); after  dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);

Don't keep a DataTable in to ViewState.  DataTable is a big object. It will affect page  performance. You can keep in to cache or session.

My recomandation is to cache the datatable datasource not the datatable object.